# append row after first row in a html table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have `var row=<tr><td>val</td><td>val2</td></tr>`
and I tried this:

```
$("#mainTable tbody").append(row);
```

but it appends to the end of the table.

Also I tried `$("#mainTable tr:first").after().append(row);`

But have not got a result yet.

Please, help me to understand.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#mainTable tr:first").after(row);
```

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: How would you add the row with effect like slide down or fade in?

Answer (score 6):

[InsertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) is what you are looking for:

```
var row='<tr><td>val</td><td>val2</td></tr>';
$(row).insertAfter("#mainTable tr:first");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use prepend JQuery method that inserts as the first child:

```
$("#mainTable tbody").prepend(row);
```

[Prepend documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)